# Jquery/html/php folder treeview

Tags: php, jquery, html, treeview

I try to make a treeview with php and it works, but what I want is when I refresh/reload the page the last folder that I expanded will still expand and not closed.
For example:
[TreeView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O86Z6.png)

when I reload the page, the treeview still opened just like the screenshot.
I did it using jstree and JSON, but I want it using HTML/PHP and the data from the database not JSON.
(Sorry for my bad english) :(

Comment: how about cookie in JS ??

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I use this script from jstree, but when I expanded the folders, the folders id not appear. 
Here's my code :

```
$('#html').on('open_node.jstree', function (e, data) {
    var i, j, r = [];
    for(i = 0, j = data.node.length; i < j; i++) {
      r.push(data.instance.get_node(data.node[i]).id);
    }
    $('#event_result').html('Open: ' + r.join(', ')); // <- i want this code appear multi values like, 1,3,4 when I expanded folder with id ex: 1,3,4
//$('#event_result').html('Open: ' + data.instance.get_node(data.node).id); <- this code works, but only appear single value when I expanded folder with id ex: 1.
    document.cookie = data.instance.get_node(data.node).id;

  })
```

my full code: https://jsfiddle.net/qtrgsg8f/1/